# Install JDK using Java

Tags: java, swing, applet, processbuilder

I like to develop application which checks whether JDK has been installed or not, If not
I need to install JDK using Java program in client side.

I referred to processbuilder, Launch4j, Ant many other installer programs, yet I can not figure it out.

There are two buttons:

If we click "Welcome" button, it checks whether jdk installed or not,

If we click "Install Jdk" button, need to install jdk in our system..

How to do it?

It is desktop application.

Note: JDK is packed with my exe file

Comment: Why the JDK rather than just a JRE?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of install4j to export application installer. While exporting make sure you select export with JRE/JDK option. With this you need not check explicitly whether java is installed or not. install4j takes care of it.

Comment: I tried that..My intention is to install jdk..Install4j is used to run particular java program,

Comment: agreed. If jre/jdk is not installed your program fails. And hence you can configure this check in install4j. install4j will check if java is installed, if not install4j will install java on itself **"Only if you selected export jre with archieve option".

Comment: thanks for your reply.after java codes,i change this java to exe.Now i no need to have jdk in my desktop..It is an exe ..

Comment: @Chris , pls mark answer as correct If it solves your concern. This will help others by preventing from duplicate posts.